# when I added configuration information in applicationContext.xml and daoContext.xml, Eclipse got the following 404 error

Tags: spring, eclipse

It could have been running, but when I added DeptDao.java and Dept.java configuration information in applicationContext.xml and daoContext.xml, Eclipse got the following 404 error. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you! !
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTRjx.png)
This is my mistake.

```
六月 18, 2020 7:09:19 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
严重: 异常将上下文初始化事件发送到类的侦听器实例.[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'appDao' while setting bean property 'appDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept]
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5] for bean with name 'deptDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1662)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1618)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:465)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:289)
    ... 75 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5] for bean with name 'deptDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/daoContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:670)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:222)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:75)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1063)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:437)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1372)
    ... 53 more

六月 18, 2020 7:09:19 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
严重: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
六月 18, 2020 7:09:19 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
严重: Context [/HRSystem_Eclipse] startup failed due to previous errors
六月 18, 2020 7:09:19 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
六月 18, 2020 7:09:31 下午 org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
信息: 至少有一个JAR被扫描用于TLD但尚未包含TLD。 为此记录器启用调试日志记录，以获取已扫描但未在其中找到TLD的完整JAR列表。 在扫描期间跳过不需要的JAR可以缩短启动时间和JSP编译时间。
六月 18, 2020 7:09:31 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
六月 18, 2020 7:09:31 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root W`enter code here`ebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
六月 18, 2020 7:09:33 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springmvc'
六月 18, 2020 7:09:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: 把web 应用程序部署到目录 [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.31-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.31\webapps\docs]
六月 18, 2020 7:09:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deployment of web application directory [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.31-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.31\webapps\docs] has finished in [72] ms
六月 18, 2020 7:09:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
...
六月 18, 2020 7:09:40 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
信息: 开始协议处理句柄["http-nio-8888"]
六月 18, 2020 7:09:40 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
信息: Server startup in [43,707] milliseconds
```

This is applicationContext.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- 定义业务逻辑组件模板,为之注入DAO组件 -->
    <bean id="managerTemplate" abstract="true" lazy-init="true"
        p:appDao-ref="appDao"
        p:attendDao-ref="attendDao"
        p:typeDao-ref="attendTypeDao"
        p:checkDao-ref="checkDao"
        p:empDao-ref="employeeDao"
        p:mgrDao-ref="managerDao"
        p:payDao-ref="payDao"
        p:deptDao-ref="deptDao"
        />
        <!-- p:deptDao-ref="deptDao" -->

    <!-- 定义两个业务逻辑组件，继承业务逻辑组件的模板 -->
    <bean id="empManager"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.service.impl.EmpManagerImpl"
        parent="managerTemplate"/>
    <bean id="mgrManager"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.service.impl.MgrManagerImpl"
        parent="managerTemplate"/>

    <!-- cronExpression指定Cron表达式：每月3日2时启动 -->
    <bean id="cronTriggerPay" 
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean"
        p:cronExpression="0 0 2 3 * ? *">
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <!-- 使用嵌套Bean的方式来定义任务Bean
                jobClass指定任务Bean的实现类 -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean"
                p:jobClass="org.crazyit.hrsystem.schedule.PayJob"
                p:durability="true">
                <!-- 为任务Bean注入属性 -->
                <property name="jobDataAsMap">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="empMgr" value-ref="empManager"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 定义触发器来管理任务Bean 
        cronExpression指定Cron表达式：周一到周五7点、12点执行调度-->
    <bean id="cronTriggerPunch" 
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean"
        p:cronExpression="0 0 7,12 ? * MON-FRI">
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <!-- 使用嵌套Bean的方式来定义任务Bean
                jobClass指定任务Bean的实现类 -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean"
                p:jobClass="org.crazyit.hrsystem.schedule.PunchJob"
                p:durability="true">
                <!-- 为任务Bean注入属性 -->
                <property name="jobDataAsMap">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="empMgr" value-ref="empManager"/>
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- 执行实际的调度调度 -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="cronTriggerPay"/>
                <ref bean="cronTriggerPunch"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 配置Hibernate的局部事务管理器，使用HibernateTransactionManager类 
        并注入SessionFactory的引用 -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class=
        "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/> 
    <!-- 配置事务增强处理Bean,指定事务管理器 -->
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <!-- 用于配置详细的事务语义 -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- 所有以'get'开头的方法是read-only的 -->
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <!-- 其他方法使用默认的事务设置 -->
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
    <aop:config>
        <!-- 配置一个切入点，匹配empManager和mgrManager
            两个Bean的所有方法的执行 -->
        <aop:pointcut id="leePointcut"
            expression="bean(empManager) or bean(mgrManager)"/>
        <!-- 指定在leePointcut切入点应用txAdvice事务增强处理 -->
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" 
            pointcut-ref="leePointcut"/>
    </aop:config>   
</beans>
```

This is daoContext.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="GBK"?>
    <!-- 指定Spring配置文件的Schema信息 -->
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- 定义数据源Bean，使用C3P0数据源实现 -->
    <!-- 并设置连接数据库的驱动、URL、用户名、密码，
    连接池最大连接数、最小连接数、初始连接数等参数  -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hrSystem?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useSSL=true"
        p:user="root"
        p:password="12345"
        p:maxPoolSize="200"
        p:minPoolSize="2"
        p:initialPoolSize="2"
        p:maxIdleTime="20"/>

    <!-- 定义Hibernate的SessionFactory，并依赖注入数据源，注入上面定义的dataSource -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <!-- annotatedClasses属性用于列出全部持久化类 -->
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <!-- 以下用来列出Hibernate的持久化类 -->
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Application</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Attend</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.AttendType</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.CheckBack</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Employee</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Manager</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Payment</value>
                <value>org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- 定义Hibernate的SessionFactory的属性 -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <!-- 指定数据库方言、是否自动建表、是否生成SQL语句等  -->
            <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.format_sql=true
            #开启二级缓存
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
            #设置二级缓存的提供者                             
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- 配置DAO组件的模板 -->
    <bean id="daoTemplate" abstract="true" lazy-init="true"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>

    <bean id="employeeDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="managerDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.ManagerDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="attendDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.AttendDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="attendTypeDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.AttendTypeDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="appDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.ApplicationDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="checkDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.CheckBackDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="payDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.PaymentDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/>

    <bean id="deptDao"
        class="org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5"
        parent="daoTemplate"/> 
</beans>
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: The exception tells ypu all you need. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crazyit.hrsystem.domain.Dept` is quite clear. The class doesn't exist.

Comment: The same applies to `org.crazyit.hrsystem.dao.impl.DeptDaoHibernate5`, that is a classnotfoundexception as well.

Comment: They all defined, I don't know why they can't be found

Comment: It isn't else it wouldn't fail. So either you didn't compile it or it isn't in the place where you said it would be. The exception isn't wrong, it is telling you simply the truth.